# Creating separate regions of a mapped file to write and read simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, file-io, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to create a file on a SSD disk and map it for one-writer-many-reader applications, and to be able to make it safe I would like to divide the file into sectors/regions. So while the writer is writing data to its exclusively owned region, the readers can create views and reach the data from the part which is flagged let's say "*available*".

As soon as the writer inputs the new data, the "*available*" sector/region should include the newly added data as well for the reader applications.

The file size is known from the beginnig so no need for any kind of dynamic memory operation, but it will be big like over 55GB(it means it is too big to map all the file at one time). The data writing is pretty fast like 15 packages per second with each package size 1.5MB.

The OS will be Win 7 x64.

Is it possible to implement this kind of mechanism? I couldn't find any example, tutorial or any kind of document on internet, they just give simple examples like creating a file and creating a view etc... I need to know how to implement such pointer operations to divide the file into sectors and change the parts from "*reserved*"(for writing) and "*available*"(for reading). (I'm not very familiar with C++ language)

Comment: There is no memory mapped file API for such thing. You will need to add such logic on top yourself. But instead of "implement such pointer operations" you will need to create and release different views from the file.
Are you sure though this is what you need. Why all the data needs to be in a single file? Also in general memory mapped files are relatively slower because of the paging mechanism they have. You are about to create one extra on top of that - it will be probably better if you just use files and read the packages in the memory.

Comment: You "create a view" just by opening the file.  The also OS provides some locking primitives, either for locking the whole file or a range of bytes.  If they do not do what you need, then you will need to build your own.  If locks only need to be enforced while the app is active, you could do something entirely in memory; if they need to persist, they need to be on disk.  And, what are your consistency requirements?  In short, you've given a tall order, and you've got some work to do to flesh out your requirements and map them onto OS primitives.

Comment: In this case I think the easier is to create several memory-mapped files, the files can be named so you create as many as you want and the clients decide which one corresponds to them

Comment: Yes, I think so. One tip - since this is windows OS, make sure that the files layout do not include more that 512 files per directory (layout them in sub directories if needed) - else you will discover how slow windows could be if there are a lot of files in the same directory.

Comment: I chose memory mapped files because of the performance benefit? Is there a faster way? I was thinking about implementing a circular buffer into a file and make the writing and reading operations from this buffer. So is it possible to do this way or any other specific/concrete solution please...

Comment: In my experience benefit from memory mapped files comes only if there is multiple small operations in same area that will allow multiple hard drive operations to be combined. Since you going to release all the memory between writing and reading I will assume that you will have negative performance impact. Keep in mind that even if you use "normal" files most of the memory will be cached from the OS anyway if possible.